# How can I do something like Photoshop's warp tool with open source software?

Tags: software, gimp, image-manipulation, open-source

Using Photoshop, I can edit an image by using tthe lasso tool and warp tool. I need a open source solution that will operate in  similar way. I tried Gimp software, but there is no warp tool in that. Is there a way to do something similar with Gimp or other open source software?

**Update:**

Thanks for all your replies.I found the warp tool in Gimp to warp the image but they dont show the preview in main screen its showing the warping preview in warping dialog box.
My main motto of my project is to wear the dress to suite the models (i.e) I want to wear the dress or fit exactly to the model.

In the Photoshop,the model is one layer and dress in another layer so I can easily warp the cloth to fit to the model like below. The below is the screen shot.

[image]

But,In the gimp I can warp the dress in warp dialog box only.I cant see the preview in main screen of gimp.After clicking the "ok" button the warp will be applied in dress. 
And below is the screenshot of it.

[image]

Can I have any preview options in GIMP like Photoshop? Can some one suggest anyother opensource software or free software?

Comment: Do you mean "open source" (i.e. the source code is available for everyone to modify) or "free" (i.e. you don't need to pay for it)?

Comment: This is not a photography-specific question, more of a software question.  I'd suggest the superuser site.

Comment: If you can reword this to ask how you can do this particular thing in the process of editing a photo for some purpose (retouching, for example), it will probably be left open and may be upvoted instead of downvoted.

Comment: As of Gimp 2.10 there is a Warp tool: https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-warp.html

Answer (score 4):

How about GIMP?  It should be there under filters.  In 2.8 it is the IWarp filter under the Distort section.  There is also a Warp filter under the Map section, depending on which type you are looking for.

Update: If you are simply looking for a more user friendly implementation, then you are unlikely to find anything that matches Photoshop for less than Photoshop.  There is a reason people still spent $600 (or $20 a month now) to use Photoshop.  It's the smoothest and most refined product out there by a long shot.  If GIMP can't do it the way you want, you generally aren't going to find much other than Photoshop that will.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have editted my question, Please have a look. I can warp but there is no preview option in Gimp. I have explained it in detail, in my updated section. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Gimp is great for the price and probably about as good as Free Open Source editors get but it lacks the kind of polish you get with a professional product as you've discovered.

Comment: There is a [cage transform tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLt3Uo5cMbA). Crashes a ton, though.